# detached entity passed to persist: com.carpooling.entity.Role; nested exception is org.hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using spring boot and spring data in my projet:

```
@Entity
public class User {
   vate Long       id;
   private String     firstName;
   private String     familyName;
   @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
   @JoinTable( name = "user_role", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn( name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false ) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn( name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false ) } )
private List<Role> roles;
//getters and setters
 }
```

the Role class:

```
@Entity
 public class Role {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
   private Long       id;
   private String     roleName;

   @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles" )
    private List<User> users;
   //getters and setters
 }
```

add User methode:

```
public User AddUser( User user ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
    user.setRoles( roles );
    return userRepsitory.save( user );
}
```

when i tried to add a new user it gives me the error above, heres the JSON object sent:

> {"firstName":"fff","familyName":"ffff","roles":[{"id":1}, {"id":2}]
>       }

Comment: You should never replace the collection. Only remove from and add to it.

Comment: @Bart that would make no difference actually

Comment: @AmerQarabsa Just a precaution and not the solution. I just commented because I saw OP using a setter for the collection. It's a recipe for errors.

Comment: @Bart in that case I agree completely with you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are cascading a none managed entities, if your entities do have id( like your case) jpa will consider them to be detached entities and you need either to make them managed, you can simply fetch the roles from your database using the provided id.

```
public User AddUser( User user ) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
 for(Role entry :user.getRoles()) 
    roles.add(roleDao.findOne(entry.getId()));
user.setRoles( roles );
return userRepsitory.save( user );
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Amer Qarabsa you helped twice yesterday and today..keep going you are doing a great work

Comment: @imsiimsi is that solves your issue feel free to accept the answer , im glad i could help